# Find the sum of all elements in array recursively in java language

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, sum

Here is my code:

```
public int sum(int[] array, int index) 
  {
    //int index is the number of elements in the array. 
       //Here is my base case:
    if (index == 0)
        return 0;
    //Now it's time for the recursion
    else
        return array[index] + sum(array, index + 1);
}
```

I keep on getting an out of bounds error, but I don't what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Where is your stop condition ? You don't have one and you keep increasing index.

Answer (score 8):

Your base condition is faulty. It should be:

```
if (index == array.length)
```

Note, you need to pass `index = 0` on first call. If you are passing `index = array.length - 1`, then keep the base case as it is, and change the recursive method invocation to pass `index - 1`, instead of `index + 1`.

However, do you really need recursion? I would seriously give it hundreds of thoughts before reaching out for recursion instead of loop for this task.

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int arr[] = {3, 4, 6, 7};
    System.out.println(sum(arr, arr.length-1));

}

public static int sum(int[] array, int index) {
    if (index == 0) {
        return array[0];
    } else {
        return array[index] + sum(array, index - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: if index is the number of elements in the array, sum({9}, 1) would throw index out of range: array[1] + sum(array, 0). There is only one element in the array, array[1] doesn't exist.

Comment: Look at my main method. that should be `sum({9},0)`

Comment: what about array is empty. you have a negative index.

Answer (score 1):

instead of going from 0 to highest index , go from highest index to 0, i did (index -1) because you said index is total elements, so if array has 10 elements, last element has index 9

```
public int sum(int[] array, int index) 
  {
    //int index is the number of elements in the array. 
       //Here is my base case:
    if (index == 0)
        return 0;
    //Now it's time for the recursion
    else
        return array[index-1] + sum(array, (index - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@ Masud  - you're code has a logical error though (i'm beginner Java so sorry if i'm incorrect).

```
return array[index] + sum(array, index - 1);

     array[index]
```

will receive a out-of-bounds error as index starts at 0 - hence meaning there won't be an index there. 
'index - 1' would work.
Also, this would change your base case to return '0' as returning array[0] will have array[0] added twice and an incorrect sum.

This is my code:

```
public static int sumArrayRecursion(int array[], int n){
    if (n == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return array[n-1] + sumArrayRecursion(array, n-1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 1.8 you can do the following

```
public int sum(int[] array) 
{
     return (int)array.stream().sum();
}
```

or even

```
public int sum(int[] array) 
{
     return (int)array.sum();
}
```